# NetBeans 7.3 freeform Java project - how to add a 3d party library to the project.xml?

Tags: java, xml, netbeans

I have a **freeform** Java project (with my own build.xml file) in NetBeans 7.3 and I need to add a 3d party library jar to this project. I know how to do that to build and run, but when **editing** I still see warnings about "cannot find symbol...". When I open the project properties and click on "Java Sources Classpath" I see the "Add JAR/Folder" button as **inactive** (why? I don't know, I couldn't find a way to change that). I know that I can edit the project "nbproject/project.xml" file manually, but I need an exact syntax.

Could you please give me a piece of advice, how to add a library jar into the "nbproject/project.xml" file for a freeform NetBeans project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I can answer my own question now - thanks to the NetBeans plugin, called "Freeform Project Extras", which provides a number of new templates and some documentation about the "project.xml" layout. So, the "project.xml" should contain the following XML element (in its simplest form):

```
    <java-data xmlns="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/freeform-project-java/2">
        <compilation-unit>
            <package-root>${basedir}</package-root>
            <classpath mode="compile">abc.jar:xyz.jar</classpath>
        </compilation-unit>
    </java-data>
```

It's essential to refer to the **second** version of the XML schema here.